# getting unknown path with Json

Tags: html, css, json, ajax, slideshow

```
[
  {
    "src" : "./images/slide-1.png",
    "alt" : "Slide one"
  },
  {
    "src" : "./images/slide-2.png",
    "alt" : "Slide two"
  },
  {
    "src" : "./images/slide-3.png",
    "alt" : "Slide three"
  },
  {
    "src" : "./images/slide-4.png",
    "alt" : "Slide four"
  }
]

//slide show
  var slides = $('.sidenav li');
  var slideIndex = 0;
  var slideTime = animate();

  slideTo(slides[0]);

  slides.click(function() {

    clearInterval(slideTime);
    slideTime = animate();

    var selectedIndex = $(this).index();
    var slide = slides[selectedIndex];
    slideTo(slide);

  });

  function slideTo(slide) {
    slides.removeClass("selected");
     $(slide).addClass("selected");
     slideIndex = jQuery(slide).index();
 }

  function animate() {
    return setInterval(function() {
              var slide = slides[slideIndex];
              slideTo(slide)
              slideIndex++;
              if (slideIndex == slides.length) {
                slideIndex = 0;
              }
          }, 3000);
  }

  //Json
  var image = $('.sidenav li');
  $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/data.json', function(result){
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    console.log(result);
    for (j = 0 ; j<result.length ; j++) {
      $('.sidenav').append('<li class="selected"><img src="" alt=""></li>');
    }

    image.each(function(e){
        $(this).find('img').attr('src',result[i].src);
        $(this).find('img').attr('alt',result[i].alt);
        i++;
    });
  });


<section class="section-slider">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="inner-cont">
          <div class="title">
            <h1 class="black title-section">EXPECT NOTHING ORDINARY</h1>
          </div>
          <p class="txt black">
            Eastern & Oriental Plc is an AIM quoted real estate company, headquartered in the United Kingdom and focused on the development of residential and mixed-use assets in the London and the South East of England.
          </p>
          <div class="bot-link">
            <a href="javascript:;">VIEW OUR COMPANY PROFILE<span class="s s-right_arrow"><span class="hide">arrow</span></span></a>
          </div>
          <div class="anchor-sign">
            <a class="anchor-link" href="#s-three"><span class="s s-next"><span class="hide">arrow</span></span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <ul class="sidenav">
          <!-- <li class="selected"><img src=" " alt=""></li>
          <li><img src=" " alt=""></li>
          <li ><img src=" " alt=""></li>
          <li><img src=" " alt=""></li> -->
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

I put the code first so now i can write the question. I am trying to make a slideshow. As you can see in the `.sidenav`, I have 4 `<li>` elements that are commented. They should be added with Jquery and filled with JSON. In the JSON part I am trying to make a `<li>` for every img ...thereby 4 elements in this case , and fill them with `src` and  `alt` . But , all I get is empty . Nothing . There are no errors but when I check if something was added , I can see this :
[image]

Why is it unknown? Any thoughts ?

Comment: it is because `<li><img src=" " alt=""></li>` "src" is empty

Comment: @J.vee it has to be empty ... I need to fill it with Jquery and JSON

Comment: try to uncomment  `<!-- <li class="selected"><img src=" " alt=""></li>
          <li><img src=" " alt=""></li>
          <li ><img src=" " alt=""></li>
          <li><img src=" " alt=""></li> -->`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i cannot replicate your exact code and values i made a simple snippet below.

I don't know why you use `i++` because the `each` function has an index as argument and you can use it.

In the below snippet everything works ( i think ) as you expected.

```js
let result = [{
  "src": "./images/slide-1.png",
  "alt": "Slide one"
}, {
  "src": "./images/slide-2.png",
  "alt": "Slide two"
}, {
  "src": "./images/slide-3.png",
  "alt": "Slide three"
}, {
  "src": "./images/slide-4.png",
  "alt": "Slide four"
}, {
  "src": "./images/slide-5.png",
  "alt": "Slide five"
}, {
  "src": "./images/slide-6.png",
  "alt": "Slide six"
}];

for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

  $('.image').append(`<li class="selected"><img src="${result[i].src}" alt="${result[i].alt}"></li>`);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="image">

</ul>
```

Comment: Yeah but if someone adds 1 more image , this doesn't work anymore ... I need it to be added dynamically . I have to first make li/div-s for each image I have in my JSON . Than to fill them with the images from the same . It all has to be generated automatically .

Comment: well this isn't part of your original question. So you want a dynamically generated JSON or a html structure? or how do you get the image src ? it's added in the JSON when someone adds a new image ?

Comment: I have JSON. I want a dynamically generated HTML with jquery and than also dynamically fill the `src` and `alt` tags with image sources that I have in the Json

Comment: how can it be `$(image).each` if you only have one .image ?

Comment: This worked ! Nice ! I can see my images now but the slideshow isn't moving the pictures now ...hmm.. Well this solved the part of my problem ! Thanks ::)

Comment: Glad i could help. If this solved your question ( not your entire problem ) please rate the answer as accepted. So other users can be comfortable using this solution for this particular question